# Date or Time From/To

Tags: labels, calendar, datetimepicker

I have a filter that allows the user to specify a date/time from/to within one field. The field has a popup calendar that enables date selection and right below the calendar, still in the same pop up, the user has some time selection as well.

For the label for this field, I'm not sure whether to call it "Date From" and "Date To" or "Time From" and "Time To".

I supposed there is also the option to have both "Date/Time From" and "Date/Time To" but I'm not sure if that is as clean.

[image: Audit Filter Image]

Comment: Can you post a simple mock?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why mention date or time at all in the title? **From** and **To** should be sufficient when combined with showing the little calendar icon.

Comment: I would also go for this solution and give a hint with the placeholder. Validation should take care of the rest.

Comment: Agree. And if this is too vague - maybe add a more explicit label including the relevant verb (e.g. executed) - and then "from" and "to"

Answer (score 3):

Definitely Date / Time From and Date / Time To, because otherwise user could forget to enter one of the two.

Or separate it completely, if possible.

Comment: Not so "definitely." I tend to use labels that say as little as necessary. In this case the user doesn't need the label to say date or time since the control is a pop-up that only allows them to select dates and times.

Comment: Agree with Ken. This is cumbersome and most likely to make the user miss the label altogether.

Answer (score 0):

here's a pattern GDS recommend. It allows flexible date selection e.g. just year or exact date.

With the year only entry a calendar control would require more work from the user.

[image]

Edit: GDS are the Uk Governments Digital Service and everything they do has gone through user testing.

This pattern has no submit function. It's an on-return function.